# How to remove a json string from list in python

Tags: python, json, list

I have two list with particular data I would like to merge them into a single list with out duplicates.

```
list1 =[{"id": "123","Name": "Sam", "Age": 10},{"id": "124","Name": "Ajay", "Age": 10}]

list2 =[{"id": "123","Name": "Sam"},{"id": "124","Name": "Ajay"},{"id": "125","Name": "Ram"}]
```

The output list should be like this

```
output= [{"id": "123","Name": "Sam", "Age": 10},{"id": "124","Name": "Ajay", "Age": 10},{"id": "125","Name": "Ram"}]
```

Comment: Have you done any work on this yourself? If so, where did you get stuck? You basically have Python lists with dictionaries, this is not specific to JSON.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I tried using list2.remove(list1) but it did not work correctly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably it is the `id` key that uniquely identifies the information. If so, collect all the info from the two lists in a dictionary, then produce a new list from that:

```
from itertools import chain

per_id = {}
for info in chain(list1, list2):
    per_id.setdefault(info['id'], {}).update(info)

output = list(per_id.values())  # Python 2 and 3 compatible
```

Demo:

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> list1 = [{'Age': 10, 'id': '123', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'Age': 10, 'id': '124', 'Name': 'Ajay'}]
>>> list2 = [{'id': '123', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'id': '124', 'Name': 'Ajay'}, {'id': '125', 'Name': 'Ram'}]
>>> per_id = {}
>>> for info in chain(list1, list2):
...     per_id.setdefault(info['id'], {}).update(info)
...
>>> list(per_id.values())
[{'Age': 10, 'id': '123', 'Name': 'Sam'}, {'Age': 10, 'id': '124', 'Name': 'Ajay'}, {'id': '125', 'Name': 'Ram'}]
```