# How to remove a json string from list in python without losing data

Tags: python, json, list

My question is similar to that of another question in SO [How to remove a json string from list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33735914/5039470).
The solution to that question did solve a part of my problem but mine is little different.

My lists are:

```
list1 = [{"ID": 1, "data": "12"},{"ID": 2, "data": "13"}]
list2 = [{"ID": 1, "col": "5"},{"ID": 1, "col": "8"},{"ID": 2,"col": "2"}]
```

I did the following to modify the final list:

```
per_id = {}
for info in chain(list1, list2):
    per_id.setdefault(info['ID'], {}).update(info)

output = list(per_id.values())
```

The expected output was:

```
output = [{"ID": 1,"data": "12", "col": "5"},{"ID": 1,"data": "12", "col": "8"},{"ID": 2,"data": "13","col": "2"}]
```

But the output i got is:

```
output = [{"ID": 1,"data": "12", "col": "5"},{"ID": 2,"data": "13","col": "2"}]
```

Is there a way to rectify this problem.

Comment: Is it `info['id']` or `info['ID']`?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu its `info['ID']` my bad.

Comment: What's the expected result when there are more than one value with the same `ID` in both list.

Comment: @luoluo Only one list have the same `ID` more than once

Answer (score 0):

You get the second version because there is more than one "ID" with the the value of 1. If you use a [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) with a list, you can set it to append.

This example is taken directly from the page:

```
>>> s = [('yellow', 1), ('blue', 2), ('yellow', 3), ('blue', 4), ('red', 1)]
>>> d = defaultdict(list)
>>> for k, v in s:
...     d[k].append(v)
...
>>> d.items()
[('blue', [2, 4]), ('red', [1]), ('yellow', [1, 3])]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have one list that contains some attributes for an ID and another one that contains other attributes, chaining is probably not the best idea.

Here you could simply iterate separately both lists and update the map of one list with the map of the second one. Code example in python console:

```
>>> result = []  # start with an empty list 
>>> for elt1 in list1:
        for elt2 in list2:
            if elt1['ID'] == elt2['ID']:
                eltr = elt1.copy()  # take a copy to avoid changing original lists
                eltr.update(elt2)
                result.append(eltr)

>>> result
[{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '5'}, {'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '8'}, {'data': '13', 'ID': 2, 'col': '2'}]
```

as expected...

Comment: I am getting repeated values like this `[{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '5'},{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '5'}, {'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '8'},{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '8'}, {'data': '13', 'ID': 2, 'col': '2'}]` when running through python program

Comment: @Maari: Are you sure you exactly copied my code? And if yes are you using exacty list1 and list2 from question? I tried it on both Python2 and Python3 and `len(result)` **is** 3

Comment: I am getting a proper result when running on python console, but when using it from a file am getting this type of output.

Comment: @Maari: You should try to control the input lists when running from a file

Comment: Can you give me a clue on how to do that, sorry am a naive

Answer (score 0):

Try itertools-combinations-

```
from itertools import chain
from itertools import combinations

list1 = [{"ID": 1, "data": "12"},{"ID": 2, "data": "13"}]
list2 = [{"ID": 1, "col": "5"},{"ID": 1, "col": "8"},{"ID": 2,"col": "2"}]


data = []
for i,j in combinations(chain(list1,list2),2):
    if i['ID'] == j['ID']:
        d = dict(i.items()+j.items())
        if len(d.keys())==3:#Ensure that it has three keys i.e. avoid combination between lsit1 elements or combination between list2 elements themselves.
            data.append(d)
print data
```

Output-

```
[{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '5'}, {'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '8'}, {'data': '13', 'ID': 2, 'col': '2'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

The previous answer from Serge Ballesta works if you include a simple check to avoid repeating values (i would comment it, but i don't have enough reputation).

```
result = [] # start with an empty list

for elt1 in list1:
    for elt2 in list2:
        if elt1['ID'] == elt2['ID']:
            for k in elt2.keys():
                if k != "ID":
                    eltr = elt1.copy()  # take a copy to avoid changing original lists
                    eltr.update(elt2)
                    result.append(eltr)

result
```

Output:

```
[{'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '5'}, {'data': '12', 'ID': 1, 'col': '8'}, {'data': '13', 'ID': 2, 'col': '2'}]
```